# How to handle two projects in Xcode8?

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode-workspace

I have two projects called Project A and Project B. Both projects have different pod files.

Now I want to add Project B into Project A. So my Project A is final code and I want to use a Project B files in Project A and vice versa. So How can I achieve it in Xcode8?

Answer (score 0):

Create a workspace with both Projects A and B.

When you write your POD file, you can set the workspace file, the project file and the build target.

For example:

```
project '../Source/Rnd_Lab(iOS).xcodeproj/'
workspace 'RND(iOS).xcworkspace/'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RND' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RND
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

Targets the `Rnd_Lab(iOS).xcodeproj` project in a completely other directory and sets the pods to target `RND`.  Then, it writes all of these settings to the specified `RND(iOS).xcworkspace`.  This workspace is the one you would have already setup with projects A and B.

Comment: BTW, whatever you do, do not use TextEdit on podfiles.  Many people are using VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/